# hashtable contains $null values

Tags: xml, powershell, hashtable

I'm not understanding something. I have a hashtable that contains locations of External Utilities

```bsh
$ExtUtilities = @{}
```

Then later on I am adding them into the hash table  from an XML document

```bsh
$ExtUtilities.essclient = $XmlDoc.config.local.setup.external.utility.essclient
$ExtUtilities.lcm       = $XmlDoc.config.local.setup.external.utility.lcm
$ExtUtilities.sqlclient = $XmlDoc.config.local.setup.external.utility.sqlclient
$ExtUtilities.oraexport = $XmlDoc.config.local.setup.external.utility.oraexport
```

All is fine but I noticed that there are $nulls in the table for each entry and am not sure where they are coming from

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
sqlclient                      {$null, $null, C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\sqlcmd.exe, $null}
oraexport                      {$null, $null, $null, C:\app\client\epmadmin\product\12.1.0\client_1\BIN\exp.exe}
essclient                      {$null, C:\Oracle\Middleware\EPMSystem11R1\products\Essbase\EssbaseClient\bin\startMaxl.cmd, $null, $null}
lcm                            {C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\Foundation1\bin\Utility.bat, $null, $null, $null}
```

The `$null`s are messing with me running these commands as the CMD interpriter doesn't like the commands that have the leading `$null`s.

Anyone can explain why there are `$null`s there?

Comment: How do you expect us to tell without knowing what your XML document looks like, or how you load it into `$XmlDoc`?

Comment: I'm loading the XML by simply doing a get-content like so
    $xmlDoc = [xml](Get-Content -path Config.xml), but I think briantist has it right. Thanks for you reply.

Answer (score 3):

Well it's hard to say without seeing your original XML, but likely it's because there are multiple matching elements; the result of of your `$XmlDoc.config.local.` etc. probably returns an array, and some of the values are `$null`.

You should be able to filter them out when you do the assignment, something like this:

```
$ExtUtilities.essclient = $XmlDoc.config.local.setup.external.utility.essclient | 
    Where-Object -FilterScript { $_ }
```

That will only assign the objects that resolve to `$true`.

If you really don't want an array, then also get only the first one:

```
$ExtUtilities.essclient = $XmlDoc.config.local.setup.external.utility.essclient | 
    Where-Object -FilterScript { $_ } |
    Select-Object -First 1
```

Comment: Ah...That makes sense. I was starting to think it was something to do with the $xmlDoc but the pattern of $nulls per item kind of threw me off. I figured since I was asking for an explicit xml path that I wouldn't need to do any other filtering and such. Thanks for the reply.